# Occasional powerpoint slides

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow

Is there a way in PowerPoint to have a few slides not play in the normal loop but occasionally get injected at specific or random intervals?

For example, let's say you have a slideshow that repeatedly loops through 20 slides, but occasionally want a video to play, not on every loop, but every *n* loops/minutes.

Is there a way that can be achieved?

Comment: Powerpoint is not capable of doing this unless you want to go hacky and do it VBA style. But if you only want to do a presentation on loop, why not record the presentation to a video and put that video together with the other videos in a playlist and use something like VLC Media player?

Comment: Rendering a video wouldn't be practical because it would take a long time to make changes. Might it be possible with hidden slides or sections?

Comment: Again, Powerpoint can't do this unless you go hacky with VBA. Powerpoint is meant to create an aid for presentations. It has been abused for making non-interactive media, it is not capable of advanced logic unless you go the VBA route.